# how to solve $\int_{0}^{4}\int_{\sqrt{x}}^{2} \sin(xy^3) dydx$?

Tags: integration

$$\int_{0}^{4}\int_{\sqrt{x}}^{2} \sin(xy^3) dydx$$

My solution is: (I'm not sure if it's right.)
$$\int_{0}^{4}\int_{\sqrt{x}}^{2} \sin(xy^3) dydx=\int_{0}^{2}\int_{0}^{y^2} \sin(xy^3) dxdy=-\int_{0}^{2}\frac{1-\cos(y^5)}{y^3}dy$$
but I don't know what to do with rest.

Comment: Your rightmost expression is wrong. It should be: $\displaystyle \cdots = \int \limits_0^2 \frac{1-\cos(y^5)}y \, dy $

[And I doubt there's a clean form to this integral](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int_0%5E2+%281+-cos%28y%5E5%29%29%2Fy%5E3+dy)

And yes, your middle double integral is correct.

Comment: @GohP.iHan shouldn't the denominator of $\frac{1-\cos(y^5)}{y}$ be $y^3$?

Comment: Yes, my $\LaTeX$ skill failed me. I tried to fix my comment above, but I guess I can't edit it anymore after a couple of hours later.